# GORM golang becomes super slow after few queries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have a simple query that selects products and does a where search on them by name. The database (postgres) has around 2 million products, and the title is indexed to execute the search faster.

Now when I execute 5 queries in a row, the first few (about 4 mostly) execute very quickly and then queries after that go extremely slowly - sometimes over 5 seconds.

But when I do the exact same query in GORM using GORM or when I directly connect to the database, it executes it again in 20ms.

Why does GORM become super slow after a few queries?

```
res := dbHandler.
    Scopes(query.Paginate(listRequest)).
    Where(where.Main, where.Values...).
    Order(orderBy).
    Find(rows)
```

The query in question generated by GORM:

```
SELECT    
    "products"."id", "products"."active", "products"."title",
    "products"."subtitle", "products"."description", "products"."isbn",
    "products"."ean", "products"."bznr",
    "products"."cover_picture", "products"."publication_date",
    "products"."edition", "products"."publisher", "products"."stock",
    "products"."delivery_time", "products"."selling_price",
    "products"."width", "products"."height",
    "products"."length", "products"."weight" 
FROM 
    "products" 
WHERE 
    products.title ILIKE '%Warum Frauen alles besser wissen - und trotzdem alles falsch machen%' 
LIMIT 10
```

There was no other traffic on it, only those 5 queries that happen one after another, so I didn't expect the query execution on first four that was 20ms to go to 5s+.

Comment: Firstly, looking at your query, I can see that it uses "ILIKE", which means that if there is an index on the "title" column, it will not be used. The issue you are experiencing with the 5th query being slow may be due to connection pooling. When you execute the first few queries, GORM may reuse a connection that has already been opened, making the queries execute faster. However, when executing subsequent queries, GORM may need to open and close connections multiple times, leading to slower query execution.

Comment: That could be a case of bad generic plan. See if it improves with `plan_cache_mode = force_custom_plan`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works but try this,

When you create `gorm` database object try making it only once
here is the example

```
import (
  "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
  "gorm.io/gorm"
  "sync"
)

var (
    once = sync.Once{}
    db *gorm.DB
)

func GetCon() *gorm.DB {
  once.Do(func() {
    dsn := "host=localhost user=gorm password=gorm dbname=gorm port=9920 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
  })
  return db
}
```

then use `GetCon()` function to get database object every time this will create database object one time only and will not try to reconnect every time to the database and it might make your app performance better.

Although this solution might work but using gorm is very bad idea here is a link to reddit discussion [GORM is a bad idea?](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/umkgk3/gorm_is_a_bad_idea/). When it comes to larger projects i suggest using [entgo.io](https://entgo.io/).
It is reliable for larger projects and also provides great set of functionality via it's code generation and predefined functionalities like hooks, interceptors, mixins etc.
You might find it hard to use at first but it worth the efforts.
It will take about a week to month to learn this entity framework based on your capability.
It will also make your development faster because it generates necessary methods based on your database fields and relations.
your queries will be way easier after initial set up. you will be able to do complex and tricky query very easily.

also it is developed by reliable set of people like 
[Alex Snast](https://github.com/alexsn) from facebook and [Ariel Mashraki](https://github.com/a8m).

Even if you use [entgo](https://entgo.io/) i recommend using it with above method.

There is also one another package [SQLBolier](https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler) which is also very good and easier to start with but i still recommend using [entgo](https://entgo.io/)

Comment: I already did it only once in func init() and then just used it when needed, but sadly i still get this and i'm so not sure why? As everything seems fine, I just put 5 same querries in a row for a test and 4 work in 20 ms and fifth one goes on for 3-5s sometimes even longer.. I would change now for sure, but I'm in a time clutch now so i gotta try to make this thing work if possible

Comment: i think you should use raw queries if it's not very complex, gorm have `db.Raw()` function to work with raw queries.
Also you can refer this [performance](https://gorm.io/docs/performance.html) page of gorm to better your performance.
I suggest using **Index hints** and **Caches Prepared Statement** to improve performance

Comment: i forgot to ask one thing that why are you using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` it's a bad idea.